# Executing Jobs as other user

Tags: node.js, unix, ubuntu, forever, setuid

Usually executing Jobs as other user we can do `sudo -u <user> <cmd>`.  However in case of forever process we have to do this way:

```
exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' username -- /path/to/command [parameters...]
```

Ref: https://superuser.com/questions/213416/running-upstart-jobs-as-unprivileged-users

How is this different? What does this mean? Furthermore:

```
su -s /bin/bash -c bash username -- /path/to/command [parameters...]
```

does not seem to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one:

```
exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' username -- /path/to/command [parameters]
```

for starting `upstart` jobs as a user other than root is intended to allow changing the userid without leaving intermediate processes in the way; so it runs in the following way:

- `exec su -s sh`
  replaces the process that invokes this command with su, running the shell `sh`
- `-c 'exec "$0" "$@"'`
  from the invocation of the shell `sh` `exec` the command and parameters being passed after the `--` (the `$0` is the first parameter on the command line, after the `--`, the `$@` is everything after that)

The end product of this is running `/path/to/command` *as if* it was invoked directly from the command as the `username` specified; leaving a process tree looking like:

```
su [as root] -> /path/to/command [as username]
```

If you didn't invoke it using `exec`, then you would end up with a process tree looking like:

```
upstart_launcher [as root] -> su [as root] -> sh [as username] -> /path/to/command [as username]
```

(I don't know what the upstart_launcher process will look like at this point; I don't have a system with upstart on it to check this; but there will be a process left over)

Now, an important element of this is that it just calls `exec /path/to/command [arguments…]`, as if it was typed like that from the command line.

When we compare this with the second command line; most of what's happening is *similar*, but not quite the same:

```
su -s /bin/bash -c bash username -- /path/to/command [parameters...]
```

Why doesn't it work? Well you've asked it to do something different; in this case; you're asking it to run the command `bash` from the shell `bash`.

Because you didn't pass in the `$0` or the `$@`, everything after the `--` is ignored, because it's not passed into the `-c` for the shell being invoked.

### Examples of with and without exec

This collapses the process tree, removing the intermediate `sh` - it's a housekeeping mechanism to prevent deep process trees.

skipping all the execs (`su -s /bin/sh -c '"$0" "$@"' proxy -- pstree -aApl`):

```
bash,1
  `-bash,1014
      `-su,1017 -s /bin/sh -c "$0" "$@" proxy -- pstree -aApl
          `-sh,1018 -c "$0" "$@" pstree -aApl
              `-pstree,1019 -aApl
```

Adding the internal exec (`su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' proxy -- pstree -aApl`) - note the missing second level `sh`:

```
bash,1
  `-bash,1014
      `-su,1020 -s /bin/sh -c exec "$0" "$@" proxy -- pstree -aApl
          `-pstree,1021 -aApl
```

Adding the internal and external exec (`exec su -s /bin/sh -c 'exec "$0" "$@"' proxy -- pstree -aApl`) - note the missing outer level `bash`, and the fact that the `1014` pid is the same as the pid that had been present in the previous bash invocation:

```
bash,1
  `-su,1014 -s /bin/sh -c exec "$0" "$@" proxy -- pstree -aApl
      `-pstree,1022 -aApl
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. 1. Can you tell me the high level idea why this is used (I see the example of the exec replacing the current process) and 2. Why `sudo -u <user-id> cmd` does not work here. In my case I am running the command `sudo su -s <my-app-id> forever list` which always works with `my-app-id` on the shell?

Comment: 1. su is more 'standard' than sudo; generally you'll find su on systems by default while sudo is an add-on component. su is considered the shell-supported 'right way' to change the userid of a command being run. The form that was provided in the example was a simple template. You just plug in the username, and the command and parameters after the `--` and it works for any command you might like to run 2. The default configuration of sudo on modern systems is to require a pseudo terminal before it will work, and things launched from launchd/upstart/init won't have a terminal.